# Exploding recursive make with libltdl

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake, libtool

In my Makefile.am, I have

```
SUBDIRS = libltdl .
```

This is because I want to be able to use the version of libltdl included with my package (i.e. `./configure --with-included-ltdl`). However, I occasionally run into the problem where make invokes itself recursively forever. Unfortunately I'm not sure exactly what conditions cause this to occur.

This is usually solved by rerunning autoconf and configure. I'd like to know the "proper" way of doing this, because it seems this isn't it. (I also find after I update configure.ac that I have to run `autoreconf && autoreconf libltdl` instead of just `autoreconf`)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, I spoke too soon. This seems to be solved by moving the source into a separate directory (i.e. `src`) and then updating `SUBDIRS` to `libltdl src`.